# Make PHP code execute only once

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with this code.  Basically, what happens is when the page is opened an entry is automatically entered into the table and the unique ID 'CustomerRequestID' displayed.  After entering the rest of the details, the user can press 'submit' which will update the entry with additional details.  However, when the user presses submit it actually executes the initial code again before executing the submit code, creating an additional entry.  EG, if the ID was generated to be 59, the user clicks 'submit', the code creates another entry with ID 60, and applies the updates to that one instead of 59.  How can I make it not generate a second entry, and instead only update the initial entry?

```
<?php
include_once ("resource/db_conn.php");

$id = $_GET['ID'];



$query = "SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `CustomerId`='$id'";
$retrieval = mysql_query($query);
$rowCustomer = mysql_fetch_array($retrieval);

$customerID = $rowCustomer['CustomerID'];
$customerName = $rowCustomer['CustomerName'];

// creates the new supplier ID
$sql = "INSERT INTO `customer_requests`(`CustomerRequestID`, `Title`, `Description`, `RFQDate`, `Q2CDate`, `QuantityRequested`, `GST`,`NetCost`, `Markup`,`NetSellPrice`, `GrossSellPrice`, `fkCustomerID` , `Status`) VALUES ('','','','','','','','','','','','$customerID','')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$addedEntry = "SELECT * FROM customer_requests ORDER BY CustomerRequestID DESC LIMIT 1";
$retrieved = mysql_query($addedEntry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retrieved);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $cRID = $row['CustomerRequestID'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // validation goes here

    $insertSQL="UPDATE `customer_requests` SET  `Title` =  '$title', `Description` =  '$description' WHERE  `CustomerRequestID` ='$cRID'";
    $updateSQL = mysql_query($insertSQL);
    ?>
    <script>window.close();</script>
    <?php

} 

?>
```

Comment: Get rid of mysql and move to MySQLI (object oriented would be best), and do it like, yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach:

URL to create a new entry would be `http://your.site/requests/new` or `http://your.site/requests/create` or just `http://your.site/request`.

URL to update an existing entry would be `http://your.site/requests/123`.

After a new entry is created, the user is redirected to the /123 page where they can update their entry.

The php is the same for both URLs. Check that `isset($_GET['ID'])` in which case, you are editing an existing record. If $_GET['ID'] is not set, then you are creating a new record. Wrap the `INSERT` statement in an `if (isset($_GET['ID']))` block.